# maxConnectionPoolSize : neo4j-javascript-driver

Tags: neo4j, bolt

What is a realistic value for the configuration property "maxConnectionPoolSize" ? I am using bolt and neo4j-javascript-driver. How many concurrent connections it can sustain ?

At the moment when i do multiple concurrent POST requests using REST API, i get following error:

```
Neo4jError: There are no available threads to serve this request at the moment. You can retry at a later time or consider increasing max thread pool size for bolt connector(s).
```

Following is my driverConfig:

```
    driverConfig: {
      maxConnectionLifetime: 3 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 3 hours
      maxConnectionPoolSize: 100,      
    },
```